# Recursively finding files in list of directories

Tags: unix, grep, ag

How do I recursively count files in a list of Linux directories?

Example:

```
/dog/
  /a.txt
  /b.txt
  /c.ipynb

/cat/
  /d.txt
  /e.pdf
  /f.png
  /g.txt

/owl/
  /h.txt
```

I want following output:

```
5 .txt
1 .pynb
1 .pdf
1 .png
```

I tried the following, with no luck.

```
find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: What does not work? Are you missing the dot in front of the file extensions or do you want to have the output sorted numerically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `find + gawk` may work for you:

```sh
find . -type f -print0 |
awk -v RS='\0' -F/ '{sub(/^.*\./, ".", $NF); ++freq[$NF]} END {for (i in freq) print freq[i], i}'
```

It is safe to use `-print0` in `find` to handle files with whitespace and other special glob characters. Likewise we use `-v RS='\0'` in `awk` to ensure `NUL` byte is record seperator.

Answer (score 1):

Use Perl one-liners to make the output in the format you need, like so:

```
find . -type f | perl -pe 's{.*[.]}{.}' | sort | uniq -c | perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F;' | sort -nr
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a known a directory `path` with the following subdirectories `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `qux`, `quux`, `gorge` and we want to count the file types based on extension,  but only for the subdirectories, `foo`, `baz` and `qux`

The best is to just do

```
$ find /path/{foo,baz,qux} -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "${0##*.}"' {} \; | sort | uniq -c
```

The exec part just uses a simple `sh` variable substitution to print the extension.